# Was Lord Shiva/Rudra compared with a tiger or a lion in both the Vedas and the puranas?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, shiva-purana, vedic-gods

I have read in the Mahabharata that during the tripura dahana incident lord Shiva was described as a tiger among gods and as per Shiva purana parvati also compared him to a tiger. I want to know that if the Vedas or other scriptures  compare him to tiger or lion?

Comment: "how many times" -do u want number?

Comment: @YDS correction: do you want a number.

Comment: No don't worry, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , Lord Rudra is compared with lion in vedas. He is described as young fierce lion in [**Rig-Veda**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v3.82) -Mandala 2- Sukta 33- Mantra -11 .In this sukta Lord Rudra is praised as powerful deity who is destroyer of enemy.

> स्तुहि श्रुतं गर्तसदं **युवानं मृगं** न भीममुपहत्नुमुग्रम | 
>  मृळा
>   जरित्रे रुद्र स्तवानोsन्यं ते अस्मन्नि वपन्तु सेनाः || RV 2.33.11||
>
> Glorify , O renowned people - Rudra riding in his car ,ever youthful
>   .Destructive. Fierce like young lion : Rudra propitiated by praise
>   .Grant happiness to him who praise (thee) and let thy host destroy him
>   who is our adversary.

---

And here is another translation [**Rig-Veda**](https://archive.org/stream/FourVedas-SanskritTextWithHindiCommentaryByPanditJaydevSharma/RigVedSanhitaBhashaBhashya-jaydevSharmaVol21940#page/n445/mode/2up) Samhita Hindi - by Pandit Jayadevaji Sharma.

---

Western translators in their translation like Griffith and H.H. Wilson is not using the word lion but simply are saying wild beast.  Most of the  Indian translators are specifically mentioning the word lion.

The meaning of word Mṛga (मृग) refers to “wild animals” such as the lion, tiger or deer in vedas.